# How to format an arabic poem using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

This the input of a classic Arabic poem in a dynamically generated page.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor*** sit amet, consectetur 
<br>
adipiscing elit. Morbi*** sagittis consequat
<br>
turpis id dictum. Sed*** non ipsum id massa
<br>
cursus fermentum ***vitae rhoncus nunc.
<br>
In sodales dolor ***sed orci sagitti
```

The output should looks in the browser like this:

```
--------    ----------
--------    ----------
--------    ----------
```

see picture please 
(http://s4.postimg.org/bc1ahxofh/vvv.jpg)

1-Asterisks should be replaced by space
2-every single line is divided in two parts(after the asterix),those parts should look aligned vertically .

I tired first to split every line in three part using this code

```
$('div.poemContainer').html(function (index, text) {
this.innerHTML = text.replace(/\*+/g, "<span class='space'></span>");
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType == 3;  
}).wrap('<span class="line"></span>');
});
```

Then I tried to make the parts aligned vertically using css
    span.space{ display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    }

```
span.line
{ width:45%;
float:left;
text-align:justify
}
```

but without success, the text is justified but every part still have different width and so they can not be aligned vertically. so How can I fix this?

Comment: implement on jsfiddle.net it would be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to your `span.line` CSS declaration and removing the float. If that still doesn't line up sufficiently, you can set it in a monospace font (like Courier New or Monaco) to get equal-width characters.